# Is it possible to have typescript build types and only types to a specific directory?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to be able to have all of my types across packages built to a specific directory for reuse. I don't want to risk pulling in code from the API to a client package.

Is it possible to have typescript build types and only types to a specific directory?

Comment: Can't you just define your types in a separate directory and have your client/server code import from that directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes; see the `emitDeclarationOnly` and `declarationDir` [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options). `emitDeclarationOnly` outputs `.d.ts` type declaration files only and `declarationDir` lets you specify a directory to put them, relative to the `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declarationDir": "./types"
  }
}
```

If you want to build both declarations and compiled `.js` files, you can replace `"emitDeclarationOnly": true` with `"declaration": true`, and the `.js` files will go to your `"outDir"` while the `.d.ts` files will go to your `"declarationDir"`

Comment: I want to be able to build the project as well. I guess I would need 2 different tsconfigs?

Comment: No, you can do it with one. If you want to build both declarations and compiled `.js` files, you can replace `"emitDeclarationOnly": true` with `"declaration": true`, and the `.js` files will go to your `"outDir"` while the `.d.ts` files will go to your `"declarationDir"`.